# CLI/C++ link error 2028 and 2019

Tags: templates, linker, c++-cli

I've got a problem with passing templates (I think that's the cause) from the CLI project.

I've got 3 layers of classes (for encapsulation reasons and technical reasons).

I'll show an example of the buggy part (**please** no comments about the encapsulation reasons, they're not demonstrated here)

Class **A** is in a C++ DLL :

```
class A {
public:
    template<class T>
    void foo(T blah) { //Do stuff }
}
```

Class **B** wraps class A (also regular non-ref class):

```
class B {
public:
    template<class T>
    void foo(T blah) { a->foo(blah); }
private:
    A* a;
}
```

Class **C** is a ref class, which calls class B with an explicit type :

```
ref class C {
public:
    void foo(int blah) { b->foo(blah); }
private:
    B* b;
}
```

They compile alright (.obj is created), but the linker doesn't link the objects correctly.

I get 2 linker errors for the method:

> error LNK2028: unresolved token
>   (0A000645) "public: void __cdecl
>   B::foo(class utils::CustomString const
>   &,int const &)"
>   (??$foo@_N@B@Namespace@@$$FQEAAXAEBVCustomString@utils@@AEB_N@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void
>   __clrcall C::foo(int)" (??$foo@_N@Namespace@@$$FAE$AAMXPE$AAVString@System@@_N@Z)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: void __cdecl
>   B::foo(class int const &)"
>   ??$foo@_N@B@Namespace@@$$FQEAAXAEBVCustomString@utils@@AEB_N@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void
>   __clrcall C::foo(int)" (??$foo@_N@Namespace@@$$FAE$AAMXPE$AAVString@System@@_N@Z)

**Edit**

I don't have the lines with me now (not on same PC) but it says it couldn't link **B.foo** referenced in **C.foo**

I'm compiling the ref class  with **/clr** in debug mode **/MDd** (yes it has to be in debug mode because of other dependencies that are all compiled the same way)

Anyone knows why this is happening ? And more important: how to solve this ?

**Edit:**

When setting class B (the wrapper) to be compiled with /GL (Whole Program Optimization) I get a different error:
**LNK2001**:

> error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: bool __cdecl
>   Interface::B::foo(int &)const "
>   (??$foo@_J@B@Namespace@@$$FQEBA_NAEBVCustomString@123@AEA_J@Z)

Comment: What are the names of the tokens and external symbols?

Comment: Yes, the full linker error is needed.

Comment: Right, I don't have the exact line here with me, I've added a line that i hope will help

Comment: I've seen lots of these lines on google, will it help if reconstruct the lines with my current example ?

Comment: When you say "Class A is in a C++ DLL", does that mean a separate DLL from classes B and C?

Comment: updated the full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bug with visual studio's linker.

First of all, you need to set the **/GL (Whole Program Optimization)** flag so it links the template after compile.

Then you need to use one of these work-arounds:

[**BUG: LNK2001 on Member Function When Use Nested Class Template**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128789)

Answer (score 0):

This is standard lossage with C++ templates, they don't have external linkage like .NET generics.  You have to put the template function definition in a header file so you can #include it in the source code file that contains the ref class.  Just like your code snippet does.  It isn't otherwise specific to C++/CLI.

Be sure to wrap the #include with #pragma managed if you compile the rest of the native classes without the /clr option (like you should).  Like this:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "FileWithTemplateDefinition.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything... the file with template definitions is compiled without /clr anyway.

Answer (score -1):

These linker errors are pointing out that you are missing a definition somewhere (as opposed to a declaration). Not having access to your code makes this difficult for us to determine, especially without having any verbose linker errors.

[EDIT]

This code compiles and links for me just fine in a managed C++ project:

```
#pragma managed

class A {
public:
    template<class T>
    void foo(T blah) { int i = 0; }
};

//Class B wraps class A (also regular non-ref class):
class B {
public:
    template<class T>
    void foo(T blah) { a.foo(blah); }
private:
    A a;
};

// Class C is a ref class, which calls class B with an explicit type :
ref class C {
public:
    C() { b = new B(); }
    ~C() {  }
    !C() { delete b; }
    void foo(int blah) { b->foo(blah); }
private:
    B* b;
};
```

Comment: I think it's not generating the template code for the right types at compile time, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: Well, for one thing, you are not calling the foo function with a template argument:
Shouldn't it be: b.foo<B>(bla) ?

Comment: Also, I couldn't get your code to compile. It tells me:
1>3levelwrapper.cpp(24): error C4368: cannot define 'b' as a member of managed 'C': mixed types are not supported
So it has to be a pointer to B instead.

Comment: @C Johnson, It's a pointer, sorry. And normally the compiler should derive the variable's type and create the right template.

Comment: Yeah, well, it works without it just fine. Sometimes I like to be explicit.

Comment: So my suggestion to you is to comment out everything until you get to a state that your project compiles and links again. Then slowly add class definitions compiling and linking as you go.